# How can I get container ID in order to execute command in docker container?

Tags: selenium-jupiter

I only seem able to use getContainerId(WebDriver) during the first test. Every subsequent test returns empty e.g. getContainerId(SelenideDriver.getWebdriver)

Ideally I need to be able to execute commands in the docker browser container (for importing certificates etc).

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker ps -a
```

This should give you the container id

Comment: Thanks, however this will return all containers. 
What I was wanting is the container created by selenium-Jupiter for the test in question. I.e each test creates a new docker container (in parallel if enabled). I am trying to execute a command in that specific container. 

An alternative might have to be to create custom images (including RUN commands) to replace the default aerokube images.